# XtraPivotGrid dynamic dataset creation

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid

I already have a dynamic XtraPivotGrid creation, but the table adapter and the dataset are 1(one) table specific. I want to be able to get data from a table specified by user, but I can't see a way of doing this without writing about 2.5k lines of code (writing the same code the IDE creates in design time, but for any table). Does anybody think in an easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In similar situations I was creating the XtraGrid in design time, but then just changed the DataSource at runtime based on the user table selection. Then I was using the built in methods of XtraGrid to automatically create the columns. [There is an article at DevExpress that might help.](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q201819.aspx)